# Cannot get hash map value as ArrayList

Tags: firebase, kotlin, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I have a data class called `Product` and its object are stored in an ArrayList.

Then I am creating an hashmap `val prodInCartMap: HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product> = HashMap()`

I am adding the array list to the hash map `prodInCartMap["prodInCart"] = list`, where list is `val list: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()`

Then I am uploading the data to Cloud Firestore.

When I am getting the data this is the code:

```
fun getHashMapActivity(uid: String, activity: CartActivity){
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Constants.CART_COLLECTION)
            .document(uid)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val map: HashMap<String, Any> = it.data as HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>
                val temp = map["prodInCart"] as ArrayList<Product>
                for (i in temp.indices){
                     val product: Product = temp[i] as Product
                }
            }
    }
```

While executing the for loop I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
> com.example.grocerystore.models.Product

Why is it still a hash map even after converting it into ArrayList?

Here is the screenshot of my database:

[image: Firebase]

Whenever I hover my mouse over: `val cart: HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>> = it.data as HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>`

I get this warning:

> Unchecked cast: (Mutable)Map<String!, Any!>? to
> kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, ArrayList /* =
> ArrayList */> /* = java.util.HashMap<String,
> ArrayList> */

[image: Firebase]

My product class:

```
data class Product(
        var prod_name: String = "",
        var prod_image: Int = -1,
        var prod_desc: String = "",
        var prod_price: Int = -1,
        var prod_tags: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(),
        var kgOrPack: Boolean = true //true: pack, false: kg
): Serializable
```

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but it might help to know how you're “uploading the data to firebase firestore.”  Have you tried logging/printing the retrieved object (i.e. your successListener's `it`)?

Comment: I can't access the data that is uploaded, I need a separate method for getting the data which I am doing in the question. But I can access the hashmap and get the arraylist locally

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added that

Comment: Can you please add another screenshot where we can see the beginning of the document?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added that too

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more thing. Please also add the content of your "Product" class.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.grocerystore.models.Product

Because you are trying to loop through an ArrayList that contains "HashMap" objects and not "Product" objects. Since there is no inheritance relationship between these classes, the cast is actually not possible, hence the error. There are two ways in which you can solve this.

The hard way is to iterate the HashMap objects and create "Product" objects yourself, or, the easy way is to map the array of Product objects into a List as explained in the following article:

> [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: It is working but I have a doubt, I had put data into firebase firestore as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>` then why I am not able to get `ArrayList<Product>` from the hashmap after I get it from the firebase firestore

Comment: When you add data to Firestore, you should add it as `HashMap<String, Any>`, meaning that value can be any object. So when you try to cast that HashMap to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>` you get that warning. This is because at that time there isn't enough information to know whether the value is a List or any other object, hence that warning. The Firestore SDK has different flavors for almost all data types, but not for the list. That's why you should the solution from that article.

Comment: I have put it to firebase firestore as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Product>>` afterwards but also had this error that's why I had a doubt